# Installation problem. "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/target/tmp'"

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

When I was installing, I got this error from Ubuntu (dialog)

> The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:
>
> ```
> [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/target/tmp'
> ```
>
> This is often due to a faulty hard disk. It may help to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like exactly what it says on the tin: you probably have a dodgy hard drive.  Or you might have done something interesting during the partitioning stage - did you manage disk partitioning manually, or did you tell the installer to use the whole drive, or...?

Comment: told the installer to erase and install on it.

Comment: Then, yep, sounds like dodgy hardware.  If you have another hard drive available for testing, try with it.  Could theoretically be an issue with the controller as well (or even the SATA cable), but most likely, it's the hard drive.

Comment: I have changed the system and it is working fine! THX!